# Issue with Creating Custom REST Endpoint

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, rest, wordpress-rest-api

Hello I am trying to create a new rest API endpoint that connects to my database querying with mysql and then returning the id number from the school. However, the endpoint is not registering and I am getting an error from wordpress that states the following: **The plugin generated 3 characters of unexpected output during activation. If you notice “headers already sent” messages, problems with syndication feeds or other issues, try deactivating or removing this plugin.**

The code looks okay to me so I am unsure to exactly why I am getting this error.

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name:  College ID API
* Requires PHP: 7.2
*/

include connect.php

function collegeid()
{
    
    $db = new mysqli('localhost', $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
    $queryusers = "SELECT 'id' FROM `Colleges` ";
    $dbc = mysqli_query($db, $queryusers);
    return $dbc;

};


add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route( 'schfind/v2', '/schools/', array(
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => ['collegeid'],
        'permission_callback'=>'__return_true' 
    ) );
} );

?>
```

For the final result I am just trying to be able to access the data using the namespace and custom endpoint. It would be a huge help any help at all really because I am stumped as to the issue. The output when visiting the link is:

"The handler for the route is invalid." Error 500

Comment: help? anybody pleaaase

Comment: May I know why you are using normal database connect are you using the external database ?

Comment: I am trying to use the external database. I have multiple databases under one phpmyadmin and I want to connect specifically to one database and then query one of the tables it contains, I do not care if I use $wpdb or wordpress connections or php connections just want to get it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer for your question. In my answer I have made some changes with the include and also comment out the return to make your function work.

```
include "connect.php";

function collegeid()
{

    //Comment the below line to work on your query.
    return 'Howdy!!!';
    //Comment the above line to make your function work.



    $db = new mysqli('localhost', $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
    $queryusers = "SELECT 'id' FROM `Colleges` ";
    $dbc = mysqli_query($db, $queryusers);
    return $dbc;
}


add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route( 'schfind/v2', '/schools/', array(
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'collegeid',
        'permission_callback'=>'__return_true' 
    ) );
} );
```

Github link for full plugin link : https://github.com/SHABU89/wordpress_rest_api_help_in_stackoverfolw

Comment: Are you saying that adding that return command will make it work?

Comment: @oin In register_rest_route also i have made changes please check i have removed the array in callback function. oin i have checked in my wordpress instance and worked for me.  https://www.shabujamespaul.com/wp-json/schfind/v2/schools
Since i dont have the database i am unable to check your query.

Comment: oin  i have checked in my wordpress instance and worked for me. https://shabujamespaul.com/wp-json/schfind/v2/schools Since i dont have the database i am unable to check your query.

Comment: do you know how to implement this using the wordpress functions? I tried this with no luck, maybe my database credentials are wrong?

Comment: did you simply put localhost or did you put the ip of the database, maybe that is the issue

Comment: Yes i know. But this stackoverflow question was for restapi end point not working that was working right ?

Comment: You need to connect the external database with the wpdb query right ? If yes i will update that in the github link I have provided in the answer.  If this answer works for you then please click this answer is usefull button.